Не скрывается подменю навигации в браузере Chrome(в Edge как оказалось всё работает без проблем)
Сайт написан чисто на html+css
Вот код style.css (Под меню видно в браузере Chrome,но оно не скрывается и не выпадает,вообще не реагирует на изменения в файлах,даже если просто всё удалить+в браузере Edge всё работает и меняется без проблем)
Пс.Перепробовал все советы из гугла ,менять настройки браузера,аппаратное ускорение,переустановка,и тд,в других браузерах всё отлично,помогите советом,может нужно какая-то оптимизация для chrome или javascript или ещё что)буду очень благодарен!!!


* {
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: #363636;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 8%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
}

/* Главное меню+выпадение */

header nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    
}

header nav ul li a{
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    }
    
header nav ul li a:hover{
    color: blue;  
    }

nav ul li ul {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    
}

nav ul li ul a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #363636;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    }
    
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1; 
}




а где код html ?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // попробуйте ctrl+shft+r сочетание клавиш, возможно в хром кеш не обновляет ваш стиль

не получается добавить код
вообщем выяснилось что браузер chrome вообще не реагирует на изменения сайта )
сейчас попробую ваш совет

Огромное спасибо !всё получилось! оказывается так просто....=(

скажите пожалуйста эта проблема будет у всех в хроме или это чисто мой случай ?
проверить пока не могу так как сайт стоит на виртуальном проксмоксе и внутренним ип

https://i.sstatic.net/YYTYKCx7.gif я проверила, вижу стили работают, поэтому поняла, что кеш. Это обычно в режиме дебаг (localhost) бывает. В проде реже, надо наверно настраивать чистку кеш в самом приложении...
